# What is a less anglo-centric collection of persons than Andy, Beth, Carl, Debby and Earl?

Tags: examples, terminology

These five imagined persons have accompanied me for some time. We've had a bunch of laughs and a few tears. I love them dearly. That said, I'd like to retire them in favor of a more culturally diverse crowd before I start teaching myself.

So far I'm thinking that Ahmed should be included. After that I'm in trouble.

(This is not a technical question about pedagogy, but I think it has some relevance to practitioners. I don't know of any other place where I'm likely to  encounter someone who has already given this some consideration.)

Comment: Where would you teach (level and region)?

Comment: Most likely in Canadian intermediate/secondary schools.

Comment: You can randomly pick names from a list of names on the internet.  It should not be hard to generate a text file, and write a little script to ensure a diverse set of names.

Comment: There is a package for the stats program R called randomNames that generates names from a database of real names of various ethnicities.

Comment: You could just use *Alpha, Beta, Gamma, Delta, Epsilon*. Which reminds me of the [Alpher, Bethe, Gamov paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpher%E2%80%93Bethe%E2%80%93Gamow_paper)...

Comment: You may find the Social Security Administration's page for baby names of use ([**link**](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/))...

Comment: Is the question "What is a collection of names..." to which the answer could be "Ahmed, Bhagat, Carlos, Dimitrios, Edwina", or is the question "How can I generate a collection of names..." to which the answer could be "Go to this name-generator website..."?

Comment: I tend to use the names of students in the class. This delights them and engages them. The other advantage is that we don't get bogged down by unfamiliar names that they can't pronounce.

Comment: The  [Wikipedia page on common names by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_popular_given_names) could also be helpful.

Comment: @shoover The first, but I'd ideally like an answer that is demonstrably (somehow) representative of Earth, rather than my own which seems representative of '50s America.

Comment: Aladdin,Betty,Carlos,Dmitri and Evariste.

Comment: If you want to represent the world, you should also include alphabets that go in directions other that left-to-right, and languages that use other forms of writing. Pedagogically that would be bad. How about not using a fixed list, and indeed not using A, B, C, D, E that much?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has little, if anything, to do with math.

Comment: Your list ahas *already* been adjusted so that it is not all male (as it was back when I was learning mathematical games).

Answer (score -3):

I agree with Jessica B. You are giving names an importance they do not and should not have. Let's say you want to illustrate naïve set theory with examples. Just keep using different names as you go. Then you can use all sorts of names, using "alphabets that go in directions other that left-to-right, and languages that use other forms of writing."

But I disagree with her "Pedagogically that would be bad": the names we write between { } and or in Venn Diagrams are just markers which we recognize in a holistic manner. They could even be pictures or photos. But indeed only *as long as there are only a few of them*.

But then if you begin to need too many for them to be immediately distinguishable, you have a situation which calls for a better way and you can propose this as a problem to your students.